# How to get multiple counts based on different criterias

Tags: sql, count

I need help making a query so I found this site for the first time and hoping someone here knows how to do it.

Lets say my database has 3 columns (Name,Type,and Decision). In the Name field there are 100 records and there can be duplicates. There are 2 different types (online and offline), and 2 kinds of decisions (Match or Mismatch).

What I need is to get a count of the matches and mismatches for each type, grouped by the Name.

The table would look like this with the columns below:

```
Name|Online Match Count|Online Mismatch Count|Offline Match Count|Offline Mismatch Count|
```

Also if any of the fields have a count of 0, I want it to display it as 0 as well.

Does anybody know how to do this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common technique and is called a pivot query.

```
SELECT
  Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='online' AND Decision='Match' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Online Match Count",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='online' AND Decision='Mismatch' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Online Mismatch Count",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='offline' AND Decision='Match' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as "Offline Match Count",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='offline' AND Decision='Mismatch' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Offline Mismatch Count"
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
```